# How to send email with flutter desktop

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am currently looking for ways to send an email from flutter desktop. any one knows how I can do this?

flutter_email_sender: ^5.0.2 has support for only iOS and android .

I am building a desktop app that collects users inputs and generates a receipt pdf from it. I want to send the pdf file to my email

Answer (score 0):

You can use `url_launcher` package to send email

```
final Uri params = Uri(
  scheme: 'mailto',
  path: 'example@gmail.com',
  query: encodeQueryParameters(<String, String>{
        'subject': 'Your subject goes here'
   }),
);

var url = params.toString();
await launch(url);
```

This way it'll work in all platforms

Comment: okay let me try this thanks.

Comment: The sample code you've shown here is very likely to break in actual use. See the plugin's README for an explanation of how to properly encode the query string. Please consider updating your answer so that it's not spreading an anti-pattern that the README explicitly warns against.